# define a function in the GraphQL Resolvers file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql

I want to define a function in the same ts file where I define the resolvers

```
export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        books: () => {
            return [
                {
                    title: 'Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets',
                    author: 'J.K. Rowling',
                },
                {
                    title: 'Jurassic Park',
                    author: 'Michael Crichton',
                },
            ];
        },
    },
};

private export (id: string): boolean {
    ...
    return true;
}
```

but I got a compilation error

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'export'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your function declaration is not valid. You could try it like this:

```
private export function someName(id: string): boolean {

    return true;
}
```

but then you will get another error:

```
'private' modifier cannot appear on a module or namespace element.
```

so the final solution would be:

```
export function someName(id: string): boolean {

    return true;
}
```